# How to start service whenever a new application is launched?

Tags: java, android

I want to run a service, whenever a new application is started on android device.

I'm building a behaviour based anti-virus for android systems. It works by collecting system call traces of applications. Everything is fine, except, how do I schedule the service to run so that it covers all application. One way is, I schedule to run it at specific intervals. However, more logical is to run it every time a new app is launched. The service once launched will collect the system call data for the running application (I use strace program for that) send the data over network to remote server, which does all processing, and terminate. Any hints on how I can accomplish this (run service when new app starts) pro-grammatically (yes I've extensively searched before posting this question) ?

I'm not quite experienced on android. Are there any other ways to strace all application installed on android, whenever they run?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to detect the app launch. You don't have any `broadcast receiver` intent to notify when an app start.

You can start your `service`on `device boot` `receiver` and look for the running applications.

Write a custom receiver to start the service like this

```
public class CustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context,CustomService.class));
  }
}
```

and register for the boot complete in Manifest.

```
   <receiver android:name="com.stackwork.app.services.CustomReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Also , Add permission for receiving boot complete broadcast

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```